# dimple.js dash line chart

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

How can draw series 2 below as a dashed line?  If not something that can be done in dimple.js itself, how would i do this using d3.js?

```
<div id="chart1">
    <script>
        var svg1 = dimple.newSvg("#chart1", 600, 500);
        var data1 = [[{x: '01/31/1998', y: 100.0}, {x: '02/28/1998', y: 110.0}, {x: '03/31/1998', y: 120.0}, {x: '04/30/1998', y: 130.0}],
                    [{x: '01/31/1998', y: 120.0}, {x: '02/28/1998', y: 130.0}, {x: '03/31/1998', y: 140.0}, {x: '04/30/1998', y: 150.0}]]

        var chart1 = new dimple.chart(svg1);
        chart1.setBounds(70, 30, 400, 300)
        var xAxis = chart1.addTimeAxis("x", "x", "%m/%d/%Y", "%b %y");
        xAxis.title="Date"
        var yAxis = chart1.addMeasureAxis("y", "y");
        yAxis.title = "Price"

        s1 = chart1.addSeries("Series1", dimple.plot.line, [xAxis, yAxis]);
        s1.data = data1[0]
        s2 = chart1.addSeries("Series2", dimple.plot.line, [xAxis, yAxis]);
        s2.data = data1[1]
        myLegend1 = chart1.addLegend(510, 100,60, 200, "Right");
        chart1.draw();
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the shapes after calling the draw method.  They will be classed according to their value, then you can do what you like with a bit of d3.  Here's how to make the second series in your case dashed:

```
svg1.selectAll("path.dimple-series2").style("stroke-dasharray", "2");
```

NB.  The class is `dimple-series2` because it's named `Series2` not because of it's position. If you have a more complicated series name you might need to inspect the line to determine which class to use.  for example `My Awesome Series` would be classed as "dimple-my-awesome-series".  If you have a single series with multiple lines then series names and values are added as classes so you can grab whichever you need.

Comment: follow-up on this..this has to be done each time chart.draw is called, correct?

Comment: also how do you handle cases where the name of the series has characters like '(%)'?  seems like dimple or d3.js replaces those characters with '---'